# Remove background color of the page and remove the loop function

Tags: javascript, html, css

After a whole day trying to make this changes without succeed, I'd like to ask for help.

1. Based on [this example](https://codepen.io/nuton0413/pen/QWNgzKO) from codepen, I'm trying to change the background color from `'black'` to the color `'#ECEFF1'` which is the same color from the background I use on my page.

Code JS:

```
(async ({
    document,
    setTimeout,
    clearTimeout,
    addEventListener,
    installFont,
    Fireworks,
    Math
}) => {
    const { body } = document;

    await installFont(
        "Noto Sans JP",
        "@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+JP:wght@100&display=swap');"
    );

    const isMobile = "ontouchend" in window;

    const touchText = document.createElement("div");
    touchText.innerText = isMobile ? "touch to start" : "click to start";
    touchText.classList.add("start");

    const overlay = document.createElement("div");
    overlay.classList.add("overlay");

    overlay.appendChild(touchText);
    body.appendChild(overlay);

    const triggerKey = isMobile ? "touchend" : "click";
    overlay.addEventListener(triggerKey, () => {
        body.removeChild(overlay);
        
        const get_rect = () => [
            Math.min(1200, window.innerWidth),
            Math.min(400, window.innerHeight)
        ];

        const fireworks = Fireworks.init();
        fireworks.amount(7);
        
        document.body.appendChild(fireworks.view);

        const resize = () => requestAnimationFrame(() => fireworks.resize(...get_rect()));
        resize();

        let id;
        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            clearTimeout(id);
            id = setTimeout(resize, 100);
        });
        
        fireworks.start();
    });
})(window);
```

Code running:
https://codepen.io/nuton0413/pen/QWNgzKO

On codepen, in the code settings, there is a library being accessed to sync and run the function.

Library:
https://k-nuton.github.io/fireworks_ts/dist/fireworks.min.js?date=202208070212

I've already tried to apply the background color through CSS or through the browser's development tool and nothing happens.

Any modification made on this page can only be done directly through the JS file.

2. When clicking on the phrase on the home page "click to start", I need to remove the loop that the function execute. The Fireworks will be executed just by clicking a button. Fireworks will only play when the button is clicked. Once per click, no loop.

The whole JS code has only 55 lines of code.

I tried changing the background color to the desired background color, but everything went wrong.

What should I do please? Any Light?

Comment: Could you even provide which Fireworks library that is?

Comment: @YanickRochon, the only official information that I have is the Library link that I posted. If there is more than one kind of library inside the file, I don´t know.

Comment: You do not have access to an API documentation for that lib??

Comment: Unfortunately, in the codepen settings, there is only this [Library](https://k-nuton.github.io/fireworks_ts/dist/fireworks.min.js?date=202208070212) available

Comment: @YanickRochon, I think I found the documentation that you suggested me to look for :  ), [Fireworks.org]<https://fireworks.js.org/> and [the documentation]<https://github.com/crashmax-dev/fireworks-js/>

Comment: You seem to be using the version `1.3.2` of the library. Any particular reason why this specific version?

Comment: No......I don`t have a particular reason. I just want to make the magic happens. I discovered the links I sent you a little while ago

Comment: So, the code you provided is not yours, but you want to show a single firework on demand (e.g. through calling a function), and your background color is very specific, is that it?

Comment: yes, this is right.

Comment: Looks like two different libraries. https://github.com/crashmax-dev/fireworks-js/#demo.  does support changing background. 

here's and react example, but they have plain js api 
https://codesandbox.io/s/fireworks-js-react-forked-f6zbsv?file=/src/App.tsx